# ServiceStack.OrmLite Autoincrement not working with F#

Tags: f#, ormlite-servicestack

I am using OrmLite with F# on Mono.

I have the following basic structure:

```
type NestedTree() =
    static member val table_name = String.Empty with get, set
    //DB fields
    [<AutoIncrement>]
    [<PrimaryKey>]
    member val id = 0 with get, set
    member val parent_id = Nullable<_>(null) with get, set
    member val name = String.Empty with get, set
    member val lft = 0 with get, set
    member val rgt = 0 with get, set
    member val depth = 0 with get, set
```

However, the Autoncrement property is not taken into account when I use :

```
    use conn = dbFactory.Open()
    let item = ...
    conn.Insert(item)
```

I assume this is because of the default value in F# set at 0.

Am I wrong ? If not, is there a way to circumvent it ?

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is due to these attributes not being declared as inherited, and I was using them with a subclass of NestedTree, hence the issue.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9.aspx :

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
```

It would be nice to mark OrmLite attributes as inheritable so that we can inherit rather than override.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'CLIMutable' attribute.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type TestType = {[<AutoIncrement>][<PrimaryKey>]A: int; B: string}
```